# If the associated spectral measures are singular then the corresponding vectors are orthogonal

Tags: representation-theory, spectral-theory, harmonic-analysis, ergodic-theory

Let $U:H\to H$ be a unitary transformation of a Hilbert space $H$.
We know that for each $x\in H$ there is a unique positive Borel measure $\rho_x$ on $S^1$ such that $\hat \rho_x(n) = \langle x, U^nx\rangle$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$.
We will refer to this measure as the **spectral measure** associated to $x$.

I am trying to see why the following is true:

> **Theorem.** If $x, y\in H$ are such that the associated spectral measures are mutually singular then $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal.

This is mentioned in Chapter 11 of *Handbook of Dynamical Systems.* The proof is mentioned as an immediate corollary of the following:

> **Fact.** Let $\rho$ be a positive Borel measure on $S^1$.
> Let $M:L^2(S^1, \rho)\to L^2(S^1, \rho)$ be defined as $M\varphi = \chi\varphi$, where $\chi:S^1\to S^1$ is the identity map (note that $M$ is unitary). If $K$ is an $M$-invariant subspace of $L^2(S^1, \rho)$, then there is a Borel set $E \subseteq S^1$ such that $K = \{\varphi\in L^2(S^1, \rho):\ \varphi \text{ vanishes on } E^c\}$.

I am unable to see how to apply the above to our question.

Let $\rho_x$ and $\rho_y$ be the spectral measures associated to $x$ and $y$ and assume that $\rho_x$ and $\rho_y$ are mutually singular.
If we could somehow show that $\rho_x + \rho_y$ is the spectral measures associated to some vector in $H$ then we could in fact apply the above fact (because $L^2(S^1, \rho_x)$ and $L^2(S^1, \rho_y)$ are orthogonal subspaces of $L^2(S^1, \rho_x + \rho_y)$).
So I was trying to show this but that evades me.

Comment: @EddieTorresJr. Hi. I will look at it in some time. I am surprised you haven't received and answer yet.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I understand now. Perhaps my formulation was too pedantic. I'm trying to learn Markov chains and entropy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really read your question but doesn't it follow from the functional calculus?

You have the Gelfand map $\Phi:C(\sigma) \to \mathcal{L}(H)$ which extends to a map (a $*$-homomorphism) on 'bounded Borel functions' $B(\sigma) \to \mathcal{L}(H)$ (call it $\Phi$ again). Here $\sigma$ is the spectrum of $U$. We have the spectral measures $E_{x,x}$ and $E_{y,y}$ which are induced by the requirement
$$
(\Phi (f)x|x) = \int f dE_{x,x},\ (\Phi(f)y|y) = \int fdE_{y,y}
$$
for all $f \in C(\sigma)$.
Now observe that the same formulas holds for bounded Borel functions on $\sigma$. Let $f$ be the indicator function of $S:=\operatorname{supp}(E_{x,x})$ and $g$ be the indicator function of $T:=\operatorname{supp}(E_{y,y})$. Observe then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 (\Phi(1-f)x|x) = \int_{S^c} dE_{x,x} = 0.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The operator $\Phi(1-f)$ is a self-adjoint projection so that the equation above shows that $\Phi(1-f)x=0$. That is, $\Phi(f)x=x$. Similarly, $\Phi(g)y=y$.
We now see,
$$
(x|y)= (\Phi(f)x|\Phi(g)y) = (\Phi(gf)x|y).
$$
Now, if $S\cap T = \varnothing$, then $fg$ is the indicator function of the empty set.

What does it have to do with the fact that $U$ is unitary? I don't know. I'll delete this post soon if it's not helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read the Gelfand-Naimark Theorem and associated concepts (like the functional calculus) quite some time ago. So it will take me some time to understand your response. I feel that one should need to use the fact that U is unitary, or at least an isometry, somewhere since in the concrete circle model the maps are isometries.

Comment: Ok, I’m just using the version of the spectral theorem from rudin functional analysis. Around section 12.20.